# XCode: Disappear from compile sources

Tags: xcode, linker

OK, this problem is strange and I want to know if I am accidentally pushing some kind of hotkey to make this happen.  A few times a day I will lose all autocomplete functionality on a file I am editing.  It turns out that it randomly disappeared from the project's Compile Sources, and that is the reason.  Is this just some glitch that I have to put up with or am I triggering some kind of hot key that removes the current file from the compile sources?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you running?

Comment: Right, that would be important....version 4.3 (today I upgraded to 4.3.2 but it happened once already).  OS is 10.7.3

Comment: Well I'm sorry to say that I've already read several posts from people experiencing the same problem. You aren't doing anything wrong(not a hotkey issue), it just seems to be a glitch with the latest versions of Xcode.

Comment: Oh!  Well I'm glad that at least I'm not just crazy.  Thanks for your comment~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I'm sorry to say that I've already read several posts from people experiencing the same problem. You aren't doing anything wrong(not a hotkey issue) it just seems to be a glitch with the latest versions of Xcode.

Comment: Sorry this took a long time to accept, I didn't realize you had posted an answer as well ^^;